# iOS draw Stroked Arc

Tags: ios, objective-c, quartz-core

I'm trying to draw filled and stroked arc. Please see this image(Left: what i have. Right: what i need]):
[image: Left: what i have. Right: what i need]

I don't know how to set arcs join behaviour. Here is the code(arrowLayer is a CAShapeLayer):

```
UIBezierPath *arcPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];


[arcPath addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(frame.size.width/2, frame.size.height/2)
                   radius:65
               startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-10)
                 endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(320)
                clockwise:YES];

[arcPath addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(frame.size.width/2, frame.size.height/2)
                   radius:55
               startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-10)
                 endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(320)
                clockwise:YES];

arrowLayer.path = [arcPath CGPath];
arrowLayer.fillColor   = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
arrowLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
arrowLayer.lineWidth   = 1.0;
```

**Additional Question:**

How to get start and end points coords of arc, is it possible? It needs to complete the second part of my task.

Comment: For starters try stroking the second arc `clockwise:NO`. Then close the path, stroke and fill.